# Using keyboard for OK/Cancel in React Native iOS Alert throws "Invariant Violation: No callback found."

Tags: ios, react-native

*I'm trying to get started with React Native and I believe I've found a bug, but in the hope that I'm just dumb I am asking here first.  Thanks in advance for any help!*

Using the keyboard to dismiss an alert that contains OK and/or Cancel buttons in the iOS simulator throws an exception like this one (the IDs change with each build):

```
Invariant Violation: No callback found with cbID 243 and callID 121 for  AlertManager.alertWithArgs - most likely the callback was already invoked. Args: '["0"]'
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
```

To trigger the "OK" button you press `return` on the keyboard while the app is running and the simulator has focus.  To trigger the "Cancel" button you press `esc`.  If there is only an "OK" button, `esc` does nothing.  If there is only a "Cancel" button then `esc` and `return` do the same thing.  If there are multiple non-cancel buttons then `return` does nothing; but if there is a "Cancel" in the mix then `esc` will trigger it.

The correct callback for the button is called before the exception is thrown.  The argument sent to the missing callback corresponds to the button, i.e. "0" for Cancel and "1" for OK in a Cancel/OK alert, or say "3" if you have a "Cancel" at the end of a four-button stack.

I am using the simple Expo boilerplate with `App.tsx` changed to the following:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={onPressDoSomething}
        title="Press It"
        accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const onPressDoSomething = function() {
  Alert.alert(
    "A Lert!",          // Title
    "It was pressed!",  // Message
    [                   // Buttons:      
      {
        text: "OK",
        onPress:  () => console.log("--> ok"),
        style: "ok",
      },
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: () => console.log("--> cancel"),
        style: "cancel",
      },
    ],
  );
}
```

These are legitimate ways to respond to an Alert in iOS, so I need to handle them, and I would really prefer to not do something ugly like trap the exception.

Any ideas?  Should I just report this as a bug?

Comment: I've noticed exactly the same issue. Using expo. This seems a legitimate bug. You get the error even when you don't specify an `onPress` for the cancel button. I've seen other people get similar errors in other parts of react native when libs are out of sync, but haven't been able to fix this issue yet.